# How to fix axios.post without using package.json's proxy

Tags: json, reactjs, axios, httprequest

The `axios.post` request doesn't work without proxy.

*I am new in react js and using create-react-app*

When I use proxy attribute in package.json and give it my `http://url:port` in my `axios.post` I start from `/api/...`
I do not need any config like headers or allow access. And I don't need to stringy data.
My back-end is java using Apache Tomcat and in back-end I have CORS filter that only allows `application/json`
requests. When I use postman if the header doesn't match , Apache refuses the request by 415 unsupported media type.
The problem begins from where I want to use npm run build. so there is no `package.json` and I should bring my full url to axios.post's url part : `http://url:prot/api/..`
Then I removed the proxy part from package.json
Since that I haven't seen any response from java or even it doesn't refuse the request in http monitoring or Apache Log part (in Netbeans)

I did two small things and something changed!
1-Adding JSON.stringfy before data
2-Adding headers Content-Type:Application/json

Now the request is observable in Netbeans (the back-end) BUT the messege is unsupported media type although i have added to axios.post's config(and itself caused the request received )!!!
there is some thing else : when I use the fire fox CORS enable adds on every things goes grate but only with that...
*This is my first project. please explain like I'm 5! I do not know anything more!*
Or if someone has any better way; is there any way i can use `axios.post` without package json proxy?

Comment: Could you please specify your exact question? It would also be helpful to format you anser by using double-spaces at the end of a line to insert a 'retun' and using backticks '`' to format chucks of code. That will make it easier for the community to understand and help you.

Comment: My question is that how to post data to my server host without using proxy in package json? Or is there any way to use proxy in production mood in build file? something helps like pachage json's proxy?